# CRM SDK 2013 Activity doesn't exist just after creating it

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a custom comment activity which I'm updating in code and this used to work but has started failing recently. It creates the activity but when I try to retrieve it or execute SetStateResponse on it, I get "tk_comment With Id = 9a1686d1-7d9d-e611-80e3-00155d001104 Does Not Exist" - which doesn't make sense as I've just created it! The activity record shows up against the account but I can't click on it there or do anything (Record is unavailable - The requested record was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it.).

This is the code I'm using. I'd love you to tell me I've made some simple mistake :)

```
        using (_serviceProxy = ServerConnection.GetOrganizationProxy(serverConfig))
        {
            _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
            try
            {
                tk_comment comment = new tk_comment();
                int maxLength = 190; //subject has a max length of 200 characters
                if (subject.Length > maxLength)
                {
                    comment.Subject = subject.Substring(0, maxLength);
                    comment.Description = subject.Substring(maxLength, subject.Length - maxLength);
                }
                else
                {
                    comment.Subject = subject;
                }

                comment.RegardingObjectId = entity.ToEntityReference();
                comment.ActualStart = CommentDate;
                comment.ActualEnd = CommentDate;
                comment.ScheduledStart = CommentDate;
                comment.ScheduledEnd = CommentDate;
                Guid commentID = _serviceProxy.Create(comment);
                try
                {
                    tk_comment aComment = (tk_comment)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(tk_comment.EntityLogicalName, commentID, new ColumnSet(allColumns: true));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    SingletonLogger.Instance.Error("Always an error here " + ex.Message);
                }
                Account test = (Account) _serviceProxy.Retrieve(Account.EntityLogicalName, entity.Id, new ColumnSet(allColumns: true));

                //   tk_comment newComment =  (tk_comment)_serviceProxy.Retrieve(tk_comment.EntityLogicalName, commentID, new ColumnSet(allColumns: true));
                SetStateRequest request = new SetStateRequest();
                request.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(tk_comment.EntityLogicalName, commentID);
                request.State = new OptionSetValue((int) tk_commentState.Completed); //completed
                request.Status = new OptionSetValue(2); //completed
                SetStateResponse response = (SetStateResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request); //always an error here too

            }
```

Appreciate any suggestions

Cheers, Mick

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have proper read permission of this custom activity entity.
OR You need to validate all the permissions of this custom entity.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to apply - or I've misunderstood something. Security roles don't include custom activities so how do I apply permissions to them? I've tried giving myself System Administrator role and still get the same issue. Yet, for another custom activity, a very similar process works. What am I missing?

Comment: OK, it's not a code problem. I get exactly the same error trying to create a comment activity manually. I'm going to disable this one and create a new custom activity. Thanks for your help